# Android - Change color of Drawables

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have a selector where I set a circle as the background for the state_selected = true but I want to change the color when I click on the object. How can I do it?

This is how my drawables are set up:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#D0021B"/>
<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#910012" />
<size
    android:width="50dp"
    android:height="50dp" />
<corners android:radius="50dp" />
</shape>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/black" android:state_selected="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/nav_circle" android:state_selected="true" />
</selector>
```

Comment: use state_pressed.....

Comment: How do i set the color to be dynamic though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it programmatically:

```
public static void colorDrawable(View view, int color) {
            Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(view.getBackground());
            if (wrappedDrawable != null) {
                DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable.mutate(), color);
                setBackgroundDrawable(view, wrappedDrawable);
            }
        }

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public static void setBackgroundDrawable(View view, Drawable drawable) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    } else {
        view.setBackground(drawable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the color at the moment it is pressed, you can use state_pressed.

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@color/pressedColor"/> <!-- pressed state -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@color/pressedColor"/> <!-- focused state -->
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

you can also use another drawable under the android:drawable attribute

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/button_solid"/>
```

however, if you want to change the background drawable when it is pressed, you can change the button background to a different xml drawable

```
button.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.selectorDrawable2));
```

Comment: I need to be able to set a dynamic color coming from the server

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you :

```
i=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    i.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            i.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); 
        }
    });
```

ImageView xml code :

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/nav_circle"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:id="@+id/image" />
```

Comment: im getting an android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable error

Comment: Can you try like that without casting : `i.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);` Also can you look my xml code ?